# What are the limitations for a guitarist with arthritis in his hands?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, acoustic-guitar, fingering, physical-limitations

I have found that arthritis (or general hand problems/pains) is very common and a big problem among guitar players. I am currently suffering from osteoarthritis, more seriously in my left hand and I am looking into solving this problem.

If there are any players who suffer from pain when playing, most specifically arthritis, **could you please tell me the exact limitations and problems you encounter?** For example, fingers can't reach fret or too painful to hold down strings on acoustic?

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily about arthritis, but any hand problems. I suffered a slight stroke a few years ago, and my left hand was missing chords by a couple of frets. After playing and earning a living from my passion, I thought it was over. But after I finished feeling sorry for my self and realizing it could have been a lot worse, I started over. My right hand and brain were still working, so I started on open tunings just to make some noise. This was the best thing that could happen. Not knowing the familiar chords or scale patterns, it was a new start... I know the pain and frustration that you may feel. But if you have music in you, you will find away to get it out. Even a 12-bar and a slide sounds great to the average listener. A guitar is a box of tricks waiting for a magician to come along. Good luck. Regards.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Im looking into solutions on how to bring back the ability for guitarists with hand problems and your feedback is invaluable, thanks again!

Comment: @TrevorPaulBernhardt  Hats off to you and your brilliant attitude :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have arthritis, but this may be applicable:

I have had for many years suffered recurrent RSI (repetitive strain injury) in my left wrist when it is bent over. When it is bad, it makes playing more than a couple barre chords in succession impossible, and even on a good day it limits what I am capable of barring.

My solutions were:

- Primarily - play fingerstyle pretty much exclusively. This means I can often simply only fret the strings I am currently playing, and not worry about all six; the wrist strength required to barre is far more of a problem for me than finger gymnastics.
- Secondarily - just change the arrangement. Intersperse non-barred chords between the barre chords to stretch my wrist back in the other direction frequently.

I am an amateur with no requirement to learn songs "authentically", so both of these solutions work for me.

And one more thing is to accept my limits: on a bad day, put the guitar down instead of getting frustrated and down; on a good day, play as much as possible.

Comment: I would instead recommend a revisiting of your technique. I mean no offense, but playing any instrument should not generally produce RSI when played with proper technique, especially not multiple times.

Comment: I'm a programmer with a family history of arthritis. Playing the guitar is the least of my wrist related problems :)

Answer (score 2):

My guitar teacher had arthritis. He said he cannot actually play professionally anymore. However he was a really very good teacher to teach from the beginner level, and was able to demonstrate how to play simple pieces a fresh guitar learner usually starts from. Time to time he used piano instead of guitar to demonstrate how the piece should sound.

This teacher had a number of students, who all, myself including, remember him with great respect.